# problem in inserting images in database while uploading images

Tags: laravel

I am getting little problem while inserting images in database.I am uploading multiple images.there are 20 columns for images in mysql table.The problem is when i upload multiple images, if i upload less than 20 images it gives an error "undefined offset 2,3,4 etc (offset number depends on images uploading)".If i upload all 20 images it works fine.

here is the code....

```
$files = $request->file('propertyimg');

if($request->hasFile('propertyimg')) {

foreach ($files as $file) {
 
       $var = date_create();
        $time = date_format($var, 'YmdHis');
        $filenames = $time . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move(base_path() . '/uploads/', $filenames);
        $arr[] = $filenames;

  }

}

 if (!empty($arr[0])) {
  $image1 = $arr[0];
  }

 if (!empty($arr[1])) {
  $image2 = $arr[1];
  } 

 if (!empty($arr[2])) {
  $image3 = $arr[2];
 }

if (!empty($arr[3])) {
  $image4 = $arr[3];
 }

if (!empty($arr[4])) {
  $image5 = $arr[4];
}
if (!empty($arr[5])) {
  $image6 = $arr[5];
}

if (!empty($arr[6])) {
  $image7 = $arr[6];
}

if (!empty($arr[7])) {
  $image8 = $arr[7];
}

if (!empty($arr[8])) {
  $image9 = $arr[8];
}

if (!empty($arr[9])) {
  $image10 = $arr[9];
}

if (!empty($arr[10])) {
  $image11 = $arr[10];
}

if (!empty($arr[11])) {
  $image12 = $arr[11];
}

if (!empty($arr[12])) {
  $image13 = $arr[12];
}

if (!empty($arr[13])) {
  $image14 = $arr[13];
}

if (!empty($arr[14])) {
  $image15 = $arr[14];
}

if (!empty($arr[15])) {
  $image16 = $arr[15];
}

if (!empty($arr[16])) {
  $image17 = $arr[16];
}

if (!empty($arr[17])) {
  $image18 = $arr[17];
}

if (!empty($arr[18])) {
  $image19 = $arr[18];
}

if (!empty($arr[19])) {
  $image20 = $arr[19];
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $image_data=array(

        "img_1"=>$image1,
        "img_2"=>$image2,
        "img_3"=>$image3,
        "img_4"=>$image4,
        "img_5"=>$image5,
        "img_6"=>$image6,
        "img_7"=>$image7,
        "img_8"=>$image8,
        "img_9"=>$image9,
        "img_10"=>$image10,
        "img_11"=>$image11,
        "img_12"=>$image12,
        "img_13"=>$image13,
        "img_14"=>$image14,
        "img_15"=>$image15,
        "img_16"=>$image16,
        "img_17"=>$image17,
        "img_18"=>$image18,
        "img_19"=>$image19,
        "img_20"=>$image20
      
    );

    DB::table('post_property_images')->insert($image_data);
```

anyone please help me how i can fix that error.

Comment: "_there are 20 columns for images in mysql table_" Bad database design. Store them in a different table and relate/"link" them to your original data

Comment: yes you are right....images table is separate...i am inserting it using id of original table...give me some idea to fix that error please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the `$arr[] array` so that if there is any less than 20 files then it will not give you the error

```
$image_data = [];
foreach ($arr as $index => $filename) {
    $key = "img_" . ($index + 1);
    $image_data[$key] = $filename;
}

DB::table('post_property_images')->insert($image_data);
```